# How to bind ItemsControl's ItemsSource to a Property that is inside of class T from IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, itemssource

Title saids it all but lets say I have a interface `IPerson` and `IPerson` has UserControl as its property.

In the main xaml I already have a Observable collection People of type IPerson and I have binded ItemsSource with People `ItemsSource={Binding People}`

How can I display the UserControl associated with IPerson in the ItemsControl?

interface

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string DisplayName { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call that is going to add the UI component to XML Editor
    /// </summary>
    UserControl DisplayingUserControl { get; }
}
```

in vm

```
public ObservableCollection<IPerson> People
```

on view

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Padding="3">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <XXX Content="{Binding DisplayingUserControl}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I would like to know how to fill XXX

Comment: Do u want to bind usercontrol inside your mainwindow ?

Comment: No. MainWindow (Technically MainWindowViewModel but) has `ObservableCollection<IPerson>`

Comment: In your property you use for binding, use ObservableCollection<dynamic> but note that for a datagrid you would have to set the autogenerate columns to YES because the column types and names are not know until run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a property UC in IPerson interface, you can show UserControl like :

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="IC">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding UC}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion but, unfortunately I was not able to display anything with this...

Comment: When I am debuging, Im seeing the UC being null eventhough I am initializing it... hmm

Comment: It is interesting... how come Label can have a content that is not label or string...?

Comment: @publicst119 Name is a bit confusing. Actually here you can try various other container controls too.

Comment: As long as if the control is inheriting ContentControl, it can be replaced huh. Good to know. THanks again.